# CSS selector returns empty set after update

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, automation

I build a automation script to search for a keyword and scrape all links from first page. I worked fine before chrome 114 version after the update to 114 and even latest 117 css selector return empty string.

```
search_input.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)
    # Check if CAPTCHA is present
    if "recaptcha" in driver.page_source:
        print('Captcha')
        # Break the loop and exit if CAPTCHA encountered
        break

    # Check if there are search results
search_results = driver.find_elements("css selector", "div.yuRUbf > a")
print(search_results)
```

This used to print everything till 114, i tried

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
search_results = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.yuRUbf > a")))
```

but thid too return empty string

Answer (score 0):

Using XPATH solved the empty string list issue.

```
search_results = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//div[@class='yuRUbf']//a[contains(@href,'domain')]")
```